# Policy-based routing on OpenVPN server

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I'm trying to set up an OpenVPN server as reverse proxy for mobile/desktop devices, that can relay traffic based on certain policies:

- only requests to white-listed IP addresses are going to be forwarded directly(MASQUERADE to eth)
- others will need to go through another layer of proxy.(since server itself does not have direct access to non-white-listed addresses)

My current (extra) configuration of iptables is:

```
iptables -t nat -N POLICY

iptables -t nat -A POLICY -d server_ip -j RETURN

iptables -t nat -A POLICY -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A POLICY -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A POLICY -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A POLICY -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A POLICY -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A POLICY -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A POLICY -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A POLICY -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN


iptables -t nat -A POLICY -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 13579

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j POLICY

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Where `13579` is the proxy's port, `10.8.0.0` is DHCP pool, `eth1` is network device that have external internet access.

Now OpenVPN server itself is correctly configured, client can establish connection, can access white-listed ip addresses.

However iptables rules are not. Other requests that supposed to go through a "client -> server -> proxy -> server -> client" routine does not go as expected, symptoms:

- the proxy is functioning(confirmed by other means), but it is receiving **tons of** requests.
- OpenVPN client can not access ip addresses other than white-listed ones.

I'm wondering where did the traffic go after they are returned by proxy? How can I make the OpenVPN server work as expected? ... :(

Comment: Here are some TRACE log: [http://pastebin.com/3C317Z7G](http://pastebin.com/3C317Z7G)